# React: How to iterate through state and output to jsfiddle page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just learning react. All I want to do is render the output. Why doesn't my page render? For reference, https://jsfiddle.net/salvatoreasantamaria/r35ckyat/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        test: 'Hi!',
        todos: [
        {
          id: 10,
          name: 'ten'
        },
         {
            id: 20,
            name: 'twenty'
        }
        ]
      }
    } 


  render() {
    return this.state.todos.map((data) => (
    {todo.name}
    ))
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: You simply add some syntax/refferene errors: https://jsfiddle.net/kadoshms/ktcwdpLo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using map wrong, 
the correct way is

```
this.state.todos.map((data) => (
    {data.name}
    ))
```

Here you are passing each element of todos as data into the function. Since you are using react you can use jsx like

```
render() {
    const text = this.state.todos.map((data) => (
    <span>{data.name}</span>
    ))
    return <div>{text}</div>
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to render a list of todos. So you should wrap your `.map()` logic round a `<ul>` tag and create a `li` tag for each todo. See sandbox and code below: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-pine-zmpvr

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    test: "Hi!",
    todos: [
      {
        id: 10,
        name: "ten"
      },
      {
        id: 20,
        name: "twenty"
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Todos:
        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map(todo => {
            return <li>{todo.name}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `{todo.name}` to `{data.name}` because `todo` is not initialised anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In your map callback function you have initialize your object as `data` and you are using it ad `todo`, because of this it is not accessible. You need use same, you can change either `data` or `todo` in your map cb.

```
render() {
   return this.state.todos.map((data) =>  data.name)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function not the right way.

`this.state.todos.map((data) => ({todo.name}` => `this.state.todos.map(todo => todo.name)`

`todo.name` will cause the error because it is a property of object `state`, not the element in current loop.